# Only middle part should be scrolling, left&right&top of the page should be fixed

Tags: html, css

I have recently started to learn programming, maybe someone can help me? Please
**My problem:** I would like to write a website where only the middle part of the site is scrolling and the top, left and right sides remain in place. Is it possible to do this not very complicated?
Web-page examples: https://dominos.ua/uk/kyiv/ (the top of the page is fixed)
https://news.google.com/ (the top of the page + the left side of the page are fixed)
Also, here is my code so far (maybe it can help):

```
 .middlepane {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #c6e5f3;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  .rightpane {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    background-color: #084a83;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  .toppane {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: #ffffe7;
    align-items: center;
  }
 
 .leftpane {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #084a83;
    border-collapse: collapse;
```

Comment: It would probably be useful if you included the HTML that goes with this CSS, along with anything else that you're using (javascript files, etc.). That'll make it possible to recreate what you have going on and to see why what you want to happen isn't happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice learning how to use flexbox. Here's [an article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/fixed-side-and-bottom-navbar-with-css-flexbox/) that explains how to do it.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}
main {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  color: #fff;
}
aside {
  border-right:  1px solid #ededed;
  background: #36c;
  flex: 1 0 10%;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
  ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
}
.wrapper_inner {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <aside>
    <ul>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <main>
    <div class="wrapper_inner">
      <p>

Non enim praesent elementum facilisis. Facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id ornare. Lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus. Volutpat consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae. Quis auctor elit sed vulputate. Nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor eu. Imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta lorem. Sed faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque. Id eu nisl nunc mi. At erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan.

Sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus. Facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae. Mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut sem. Libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt. Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis. Adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper. Integer enim neque volutpat ac. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis. Ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod lacinia. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum. Nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Id velit ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam. Maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet. Faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu. Mattis nunc sed blandit libero. Quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor.
       Sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus. Facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae. Mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut sem. Libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt. Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis. Adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper. Integer enim neque volutpat ac. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis. Ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod lacinia. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum. Nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Id velit ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam. Maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet. Faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu. Mattis nunc sed blandit libero. Quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor.
        Sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus. Facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae. Mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut sem. Libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt. Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis. Adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper. Integer enim neque volutpat ac. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis. Ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod lacinia. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum. Nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Id velit ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam. Maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet. Faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu. Mattis nunc sed blandit libero. Quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor.
       Sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus. Facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae. Mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut sem. Libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt. Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis. Adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper. Integer enim neque volutpat ac. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis. Ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod lacinia. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum. Nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Id velit ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam. Maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet. Faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu. Mattis nunc sed blandit libero. Quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor.
      </p>
      <p>
        Sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus. Facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae. Mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut sem. Libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt. Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis. Adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper. Integer enim neque volutpat ac. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis. Ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod lacinia. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum. Nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Id velit ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam. Maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet. Faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu. Mattis nunc sed blandit libero. Quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor.
       Sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus. Facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae. Mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut sem. Libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt. Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis. Adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper. Integer enim neque volutpat ac. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis. Ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod lacinia. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum. Nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Id velit ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam. Maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet. Faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu. Mattis nunc sed blandit libero. Quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor.
        Sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus. Facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae. Mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut sem. Libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt. Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis. Adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper. Integer enim neque volutpat ac. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis. Ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod lacinia. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum. Nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Id velit ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam. Maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet. Faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu. Mattis nunc sed blandit libero. Quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor.
       Sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus. Facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae. Mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut sem. Libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt. Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis. Adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper. Integer enim neque volutpat ac. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis. Ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod lacinia. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum. Nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Id velit ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam. Maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet. Faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu. Mattis nunc sed blandit libero. Quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor.
      </p>
    </div>
  </main>
    <aside>
    <ul>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
</div>
</body>
```